# Angular: multiple material snackbar in global ErrorHandler

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, snackbar, angular-errorhandler

I use in angular the following global ErrorHandler:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private errorService: ErrorService, private messageNotificationService: MessageNotificationService) { }

  handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse | any) {
      // handle api server error
    }
    else {
      // client Error
      message = this.errorService.getClientErrorMessage(error);
      this.messageNotificationService.showError(message);
    }
  }
}
```

and the following NotificationService with snackbar

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageNotificationService {

  constructor(
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private zone: NgZone) { }

  showError(message: string): void {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.snackBar.open(message, 'X', { panelClass: ['error'], verticalPosition: "top", horizontalPosition: "center" });
    });
  }
}
```

when an angular client error/exception occurs in loops, then several snackbars are displayed overlapping:

[image]

Is there a way to reduce the snackbar showing to 1 time?
Is there a way to stop the error/exception propagation?

Comment: `duration: 3000` , set duration to close snackbar, then it will automatically closed at the moment when new snackbar is opened before closing of previous one. see ref https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview#dismissal

Comment: @GaurangDhorda: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the snackbar no longer reacts. It doesn't close anymore. Also by entering the duation or by clicking . Maybe because the error handler is being called in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a `count` variable, and do something like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageNotificationService {

 count = 0;
 snackBarRef;

 constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
          private zone: NgZone) {
 }

 showError(message: string): void {

   this.count++;

   if (this.count === 1) {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(message, 'X', {
        panelClass: ['error'],
        verticalPosition: "top",
        horizontalPosition: "center"
       });
     });
   }

  this.snackBarRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(() => {
   this.count = 0;
  });

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the snackbar (In the case of an infinite loop) no longer reacts. It doesn't close anymore. Also by entering the duation or by clicking even if the error is limited with the counter = 1.

Comment: You will have to fix why are you getting into infinite loop.